# How can i convert string format date into day,date, hour format to be same as my local machine time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this string here

```
let stringDate = '2020-12-13T15:18:59.291Z';
```

I need to have date format like this:

```
Sunday, 12/13, 04:18 PM
```

So i use there moment.js methods to get the desired output

```
moment(stringDate, "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss").format("dddd, MM/DD, hh:mm A")
```

The problem here is that i get one hour earlier then my local machine. So when i run this moment.js function i need to have

```
Sunday, 12/13, 04:18 PM
```

but i have

```
Sunday, 12/13, 03:18 PM
```

How can i customize this, so it will take my local machine time ?

Comment: `15:18:59` means 3:18PM. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I get one hour plus that is the problem

Comment: You didn't get me. You are converting `15:18:59` to 12 hours format. `15 hours` in 12 hour format will be `3PM`. Why are you expecting it to return `4:18PM`?